# Deploying multiple containers using Tomcat base image

Tags: docker, tomcat

I'm fairly new to Docker so please bear with me.
My current simple deployment process involves using an Alpine Linux image to build the artifacts and copy them to the Tomcat image in the next stage.
This works well for a single container. The problem comes in with the requirement of deploying multiple instances of the application (same ip, different ports).
With multiple containers, Docker re-uses the Tomcat base image for deployment which fails since the default server ports are already being used. One possibility is to have different volumes to maintain configurations and data for each application within the same Tomcat image. Is this feasible?

Also, is there a way to pull multiple Tomcat images for each container and keep them completely independent? This may be anti-pattern but I'm just looking to make this happen. I understand that using `--no-cache` is not an option since it does not work for base images defined in the `FROM` instruction.

I appreciate any help on this.

Edit - Note that due to an known issue with firewalld, I'm unable to use port mappings and have to rely on `network-mode=host` and edit the image's server configuration to specify the port.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the base image. If Tomcat is configured to open port 8080 inside the container, just tell docker to map it differently for each of the containers, such as:

```
docker run --detach --name tomcat1 -p 8080:8080 tomcat
docker run --detach --name tomcat2 -p 8081:8080 tomcat
docker run --detach --name tomcat3 -p 8082:8080 tomcat
```

With that, you can curl the three different containers using

```
curl http://<host_ip>:8080
curl http://<host_ip>:8081
curl http://<host_ip>:8082
```

See also https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: Thanks. Due to some unknown issues with firewall and possibly iptables configuration, I don't have the option to specify port mapping currently and have to rely on `network_mode=host`. I edit the server.xml in the image to specify the port.

Comment: No. Specifying host as the network does not require a mapping since the container relies on [host’s networking namespace](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).
By specifying -p Docker edits the iptables to provide isolation and create the bridge network. I'm reading [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables) to figure that out. So yeah, not nonsense.

Comment: You are right and I am sorry. Deleted the inappropriate comment. I never use that host network directly hence my confusion. And I believe iv you stick to it you will not be able to run multiple containers of the same image in parallel.

Comment: No apologies needed. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Upvoted since its valid but can't accept it just yet.